# Integrating Vuforia with OpenCV Hand Pose Estimator in Unity for Interactive Image Targets

Tags: unity-game-engine, opencv, augmented-reality, uigesturerecognizer, vuforia

I'm exploring the possibility of combining Vuforia's powerful image recognition capabilities with the hand pose estimator feature from OpenCV within a Unity project. The goal is to create an immersive experience where users can interact with image targets recognized by Vuforia using natural hand gestures.

Is this possible?

i have tried to edit the webtexture to mat helper in vuforia. I would like to see if someone else has accomplished this goal before i set out to do it.